# My cypress tests are crashing du to pluginsFile, why?

Tags: angular, testing, cypress

I am facing some problem with cypress and typescript on a project. When I try to setup cypress with typescript in a new project things go well. When I do the exact same things in an another big project I have an error when I run cypress run the cypress browser open, then when I click on a test a browser open and crash with this stack trace on my terminal.

```
We stopped running your tests because a plugin crashed.

Your pluginsFile threw an error from: /home/xxxxx/Desktop/workspace/trouve-ui-13/src/web_app/cypress/plugins/index.ts

TypeError: SizeOnlySource is not a constructor
    at updateFileWithReplacementSource (/home/xxxxx/Desktop/workspace/trouve-ui-13/src/web_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:740:37)
    at updateWithReplacementSource (/home/xxxxx/Desktop/workspace/trouve-ui-13/src/web_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:722:8)
    at processExistingFile (/home/xxxxx/Desktop/workspace/trouve-ui-13/src/web_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:756:8)
    at /home/xxxxx/Desktop/workspace/trouve-ui-13/src/web_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:825:10
    at callback (/home/xxxxx/Desktop/workspace/trouve-ui-13/src/web_app/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:299:20)
    at callback (/home/xxxxx/.cache/Cypress/9.5.3/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:299:20)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:5)
```

I don't have any plugin and here is the content of `plugins/index.ts`

```
export default (on, config) => {
  return config;
};
```

Anyone help would be appreciated ?

I tried removing `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and reinstalling it.

I expected the tests to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705217/my-cypress-tests-are-crashing-du-to-pluginsfile-why/71731248#comment126771537_71731248), I had two versions of `webpack-sources` coming from different dependencies. Specifying `"webpack-sources": "^3.2.0"` in my devDependencies solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try use:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  return config;
};
```

instead of export default, this should work, if not please let me know

Best regards,
Caíque Coelho

Comment: Tied this still getting the same issue.

Comment: @Spider are you using Cypress with Typescript? If yes, have you created the file tsconfig.json inside the Cypress directory? And configured the file? Have you also installed the Typescript dependency in the project?

Comment: We are not using typescript in our project.

update: We were not using typescript but we had tsconfig.json in our project root somehow. Deleting it did the trick for me.

Comment: @CaíqueCoelho thank you for your answer but I already tried with the `module.exports` and it's not working.
@Spider if I delete the `tsconfig.json` from project root I won't be able to serve it anymore.
When I read the error I am seeing `SizeOnlySource is not a constructor` and when I go in my node_modules, I see that `SizeOnlySource` is imported from `webpack-sources` and when I run `yarn why webpack-sources` I can see that I have 2 versions of webpack-sources `webpack-sources@3.2.3` and `webpack-sources@1.4.3`. And I think that in the `1.4.3` SizeOnlySource doesn't exist.

Comment: @lewisbm: try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor once.

const webpackPreprocessor = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')

module.exports = (on) => {
  const options = {
    webpackOptions: require('../../webpack.config'), // path to your webpack config
  }

  on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(options))
}

Comment: @lewisbm You should have a tsconfig.json file inside the Cypress directory, do you have? Also your tsconfig.json should have:```{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
      "types": ["cypress"]
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
  }```